# error - failed because child list cannot be created when binding textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am failing to bind text boxes to a dataset. It says saving1(mytablename) can't create child list. Here is the code; basically the problem is in the text boxes down where I have put the `********`:

```
DataSet myDataset = new DataSet("saving1");
DataSet myDataset2 = new DataSet();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset, "saving1");
myDataAdapter2.Fill(myDataset2, "extrasave");


dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataset.Tables["saving1"];
dataGridView3.DataSource = myDataset2.Tables["extrasave"];
myDataset2.Merge(myDataset);


dataGridView2.DataSource = myDataset.Tables["saving1"];
// Use the DataMember property to specify the DataTable.
dataGridView2.DataMember = "saving1";
//dataGridView1.SetDataBinding(ds, "saving1");
//comboBox2.DataSource = ds;
// comboBox2.DisplayMember = "items";
//comboBox2.ValueMember = "items";
comboBox2.DataSource = myDataset.Tables["saving1"];
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "items";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "ID";

quantitys.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataset, "saving1.quantity");*********
receipts.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataset, "saving1.receipt");***********
cashs.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataset, "saving1.cash");**********
cheques.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataset, "saving1.cheque");********
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line:

```
// dataGridView2.DataMember = "saving1";
```

line since you already set the DataSource to a specific DataTable in the DataSet